# Sobre WordPress - Postar artigos via API ou

Tags: wordpress, api

Olá,
Tenho 5 sites na Wordpress.com, e gostaria de desenvolver uma maneira de enviar artigos sem precisar fazer login em cada um...

Quais maneiras que tem para fazer isso? É Via API?
É isso aqui:
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s

Tem uma maneira mais simples/rápida de implementação? Eu me confundo toda nessa documentação.

Comment: Verifique a possibilidade de publicar por e-mail https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-posts-by-email-in-wordpress/

Comment: @JorgeCosta Parece uma maneira um tanto improvisada e desencorajada. Vi que no meio do Post diz que futuramente poderia "deixar de existir" essa alternativa de postar via e-mail. Hmm, vou pesquisar outras, vou ir vendo o que acho. Qualquer ideia é válida.

Comment: Tumblr também tem API, WordPress também.. Quem sabe eu descasco isso, mas é uma alternativa mais demorada

Comment: Daí a minha sugestão, contudo não é difícil usar a API do Wordpress mas vai ter que desenvolver

Comment: Como uma solução você também pode usar um plugin que importa posts automaticamente de outro site, veja https://wordpress.org/plugins/cybersyn/